# Bamboo build plan on branches but not on develop (aka conditional build)

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, bamboo, git-flow

This is an attempt to implement a conditional build across branches, impossible by default because of [BAM-11257](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-11257), open since 2012, still pending.

**Context**:

- Bamboo 5.10.3
- Gitflow branching strategy applied
- We would like to have a certain behavior on feature branches, a different behavior on release and hotfix branches, and a third different behavior on the `develop` branch

**Implemented (not working) approach**:

- Three different build plan
- The first provides a regex in the "Branches" tab of the build plan ("Create plan branches for matching new branches) to only match feature and bugfix branches (`(?=(feature.*|bugfix.*)).*$`). Then it provides the desired behavior in its stages and jobs
- The second one as above configured for release and hotfix branches (`(?=(hotfix.*|release.*)).*$`), then with its own behavior in stages
- The third has the "Do not create plan branches" in its "Branches" control, that is, no branching, only for `develop`.

This works fine, each branch has its own build plan based on the desired behavior. However, when merging any branch into `develop`, the three build plan start in parallel, because the three of them have `develop` in their "Repositories" as original branch entry.

**Question**: how could this side effect be avoided? How could we specify a build plan for certain branch types only and not also for the original branch (in this case `develop`)?

---

I understand Bamboo needs an origin from which cloning new build plan for its branches according to a certain strategy (the regex), but how can we block it to run the build plan for the original branch as well? Or, can we define a build plan for a branch *type* independently than its origin and based on a dynamic name (e.g. `feature-something`, `feature-bob`)?

(On this last point: in "Repository" we can specify a branch as origin, but that's a static value, we cannot put a regex there, which would fix the overall issue, I suppose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been facing similar issues. The only workaround I found was to stop using "linked repositories". Don't know if you're familiar with this but you can either use a "linked repository" which is available to all Build Plans or you can create one specifically for your Plan.
To solve my issue, I had to add a repository of type "Git" (even though we use GitHub). This allowed me to leave the "branch" field empty, thereby fixing my issue.

*EDIT*
In fact I had to specify a "wrong" branch name in this field to get it working...

Hope this helps.
Simon

Comment: Thanks for this sharing. We actually don't use any linked repository and always create specific Repositories entries for each build plan, of type Bitbucket Server / Stash, where actually you are forced to type an existing branch name (selected from the dropdown list).

Comment: So what you are saying is: by specifying a wrong branch name in the Git repository type, Bamboo will basically not run any build on that (obviously, no branch exists), but then still apply the Automatic branch management and as such automatically run builds on newly created branches? This sounds rather a bug (the functionality should apply the branch management for branches of the specified primary source repository, in this case with wrong information). Worth a try anyway.

Comment: I got it, not directly with the solution you gave, but something really similar. Since your answer triggered the chain of thoughts which eventually made me achieve it, you deserve the bounty according to me, enjoy it. I will also post an additional answer to better explain my approach.

Comment: Glad it helped you to find a solution! Bamboo is a great tool but there's a real documentation / community-articles lack :/

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to have a build plan in Bamboo defined for branch "*types*" and not linked to other branches by default. Hence, a Bamboo plan configuration which will only apply to dynamic branches, with no default branch to run upon.

The main misunderstanding comes from the following points:

- In the "Repositories" tab of a Plan Configuration, you would probably have a "BitBucket / Stash" repository, where you would select your repository **and** also a branch, you have to, it's a dropdown box with a mandatory default value. That's the main issue here. This option obliges you to have a build plan already defined for an existing branch (e.g. `develop`), while you actually would like to have it for dynamic branches (e.g. a feature branch not yet created).
- Then, in the "Branches" tab, under the "Automatic Branch Management" section, you can indeed select a branching strategy according to a regex, to suit dynamic branches (e.g. the `(?=(feature.*|bugfix.*)).*$` I mentioned above), the build plan would be cloned accordingly, but the main issue is that the whole build plan will still also run on the default branch of the default repository, something you often don't want.
- Still, in the "Branches" tab you can read that "*Plan branches allow you to run builds across different branches in **your source repository** using the same plan configuration.*". Note the bold: the branching strategy is applied to branches in the whole repository, **not** only branches which were created from the default branch you defined in the Repositories entry, but to any branch in the repository.
- That's the turning point: you can hence define a new branch, parallel to `master` and `develop`, let's call it `bamboo-management-branch`, you can even prevent its deletion or changes via Bitbucket, then use this branch as default branch of the default repository entry in the initial plan configuration. That's it. Now, you have a branch that nobody will use within the team, a build plan which will never run, **but** will be cloned according to your branch strategy on dynamic branches **within the repository**.

The option suggested [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42768227/5606016), to use a "Git" and not a "Bitbucket / Stash" repository is also perfect, since there the "branch" option is not mandatory, is an open text field (and not a dropdown list), hence you can type a non existing branch name there as workaround (note: if you leave it empty, it will point to `master` by default, as per [official documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/git-289277007.html).

Here is the forced branch name you need to provide for an existing branch in a "Bitbucket / Stash" repository entry:
[image]

As you can see, I created a dummy `ci-branch` to make it happy, it will not be used by the dev team, it's an additional branch on top of gitflow branches, but it only serves the CI managements.

Then, the branches strategy can be applied as usual:
[image]

Again, clarifying that it's the default repository the important part, not the default branch. Branches can be created anywhere in that repository and not only from the default branch. Builds will be cloned as long as the regex will be happy.

Finally, here is the additional option to use a pure "Git" repository entry and not the "Bitbucket / Stash":
[image]

As you can see, the branch entry here is optional, which also suits our needs, although you may miss some nice automatic Bamboo-Bitbucket integration then (that's why, although this approach is clean, a dummy branch in a bitbucket entry sounds still reasonable).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your explaination "the branching strategy is applied to branches in the whole repository, not only branches which were created from the default branch..." helped me to solve my problem! Although the problem is different to your question. So I can't vote up your answer.

Comment: @PeterA thanks for your feedback, what's your real issue in detail (if that fits in a comment)?, maybe I can help if it's somehow related.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but the problem is solved thanks to your help. We had two build plans (Master and Development). Bamboo created build plan branches from both build plans when a new Git branch was created.
But we wanted a Master build plan branch for Master Git branches and Development build plan branches for Development Git branches only.

=> Problem solved with Bamboo autobranch using regular expressions on the Git branch name.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to leave this here and note that nowadays there's the [conditional task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/conditional-tasks-in-bamboo-1077907046.html) which can be configured to run only on certain branches.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make a change to the regex in the first two build plans to not be execute if it contains the string "develop"?

something similar to this negative lookahead:  `^((?!develop).)*$`

Comment: but the `(?=(feature.*|bugfix.*)).*$` regex already excludes `develop`, you can test it [here](https://regex101.com/). The point is, Bamboo will still have `develop` as default Repository entry to run the build upon, then apply the regex to branching, so this would still not solve the issue (and it actually doesn't, given the existing regex already excluding `develop`). Probably the root cause is indeed the default Repository entry, not the branching strategy